# How to write parallel-map using Places?

Tags: parallel-processing, racket

I would like to have a parallel-map function implemented in Racket. Places seem like the right thing to build off of, but they're uncharted territory for me.  I'm thinking the code should look something like shown below.

```
#lang racket

; return xs split into n sublists
(define (chunk-into n xs)
  (define N (length xs))
  (cond [(= 1 n) (list xs)]
        [(> n N) 
         (cons empty 
               (chunk-into (sub1 n) xs))]
        [else
         (define m (ceiling (/ N n)))
         (cons (take xs m) 
               (chunk-into (sub1 n) (drop xs m)))]))

(module+ test
  (check-equal? (length (chunk-into 4 (range 5))) 4)
  (check-equal? (length (chunk-into 2 (range 5))) 2))

(define (parallel-map f xs)
  (define n-cores (processor-count))
  (define xs* (chunk-into n-cores xs))
  (define ps 
    (for/list ([i n-cores])
      (place ch
             (place-channel-put 
              ch
              (map f
               (place-channel-get ch))))))
  (apply append (map place-channel-put ps xs*)))
```

This gives the error:

> f: identifier used out of context in: f

All of the examples I've seen show a design pattern of providing a main function with no arguments which somehow get's used to instantiate additional places, but that's really cumbersome to use, so I'm actively trying to avoid it. Is this possible?

Note: I also tried to make a parallel-map using futures. Unfortunately, for all my tests it was actually slower than map (I tried testing using a recursive process version of fib), but here it is in case you have any suggestions for making it faster.

```
(define (parallel-map f xs)
  (define xs** (chunk-into (processor-count) xs))
  (define fs (map (λ (xs*) (future (thunk (map f xs*)))) xs**))
  (apply append (map touch fs)))
```

Comment: I did see open-place in unstable, which changes the error to ch being unbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used places before but never had to pass a function as a parameter to a place. I was able to come up with the following, rather crufty code, which uses eval:

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket

(define (worker pch) 
  (define my-id (place-channel-get pch)) ; get worker id
  (define wch-w (place-channel-get pch)) ; get work channel (shared between controller and all workers) - worker side
  (define f     (place-channel-get pch)) ; get function
  (define ns    (make-base-namespace))   ; for eval
  (let loop ()
    (define n (place-channel-get wch-w)) ; get work order
    (let ((res (eval `(,f ,n) ns)))      ; need to use eval here !!
      (eprintf "~a says ~a\n" my-id res)
      (place-channel-put wch-w  res)     ; put response
      (loop))))                          ; loop forever

(define (parallel-map f xs)  
  (define l (length xs))
  (define-values (wch-c wch-w) (place-channel))    ; create channel (2 endpoints) for work dispatch (a.k.a. shared queue)
  (for ((i (in-range (processor-count))))
    (define p (place pch (worker pch)))            ; create place
    (place-channel-put p (format "worker_~a" i))   ; give worker id
    (place-channel-put p wch-w)                    ; give response channel
    (place-channel-put p f))                       ; give function
  (for ((n xs))
    (place-channel-put wch-c n))                   ; create work orders
  (let loop ((i 0) (res '()))                      ; response loop
    (if (= i l)
        (reverse res)
        (let ((response (sync/timeout 10 wch-c)))  ; get answer with timeout (place-channel-get blocks!)
          (loop 
           (+ i 1) 
           (if response (cons response res) res))))))

(module+ main 
  (displayln (parallel-map 'add1 (range 10))))
```

Running in a console gives, for example:

```
worker_1 says 1
worker_1 says 3
worker_1 says 4
worker_1 says 5
worker_1 says 6
worker_1 says 7
worker_1 says 8
worker_1 says 9
worker_1 says 10
worker_0 says 2
(1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2)
```

As I said, crufty. All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: This looks like a pretty helpful example.  First thing I noticed is 2 is last. Why is that? Also, I see you are passing a symbol as argument, and not a function. I take it functions themselves cannot be passed as messages? (of course the first thing I tried to do was define fib in the repl and then try to call parallel-map on it, leading to an error saying fib was undefined).

Comment: Indeed places don't seem to be able to receive functions as messages, and Racket as usual gives a wonderfully clear error about it.

Comment: The order of the results is unpredictable since the calculations happen in parallel. If you run the program a few times you may have different results. If you want to get the results in a certain order you have to number the work orders and give the results with the order info back (and assemble them accordingly).